# Can I remove the text "Sent from the Twilio Sandbox Number" In twilio SMS

Tags: twilio

How can I remove the text "Sent from the Twilio Sandbox Number" in twilio SMS? Please help me! Thanks so much.

Comment: By sending SMS from anything other than the sandbox number.

Answer (score 5):

As Hyper Anthony correctly commented, this message appears when using the shared Twilio sandbox phone number.  You can [purchase your own number](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/search) to remove the text.

See the [Twilio Sandbox Number FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-the-twilio-sandbox-number-work) for more information.